# Product SKU contained in another SKU causing problems

Tags: products, sku

I've encountered a problem where I have imported a set of products from another website and in cases where a product's SKU is also the start of anothers, it causes problems where it pulls in sizes from the other product. It also causes problems in the layered navigation where a product is showing brands from the other product.

As an example, there is a product with SKU 677 and another has SKU 6772. Product 677 is pulling in sizes etc from 6772.

I assume this is to do with Magento's handling of associated products?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, it wasn't Magento's handling of the SKU but a problem with the script I used to upload the products from the other website. Products were being assigned as associated products to multiple parent products that contained the given SKU.